# System of equations in three variables

Tags: linear-algebra

$L_1 : 2x + 2y + 2z = 0$

$L_2 : -2x + 5y + 2z = 1$

$L_3 : 8x + y + 4z = -1$

Answer: $\{(x,y,z)\} = \left\{\left(\frac{-1}{7} - \frac{1}{3}t, \frac{1}{7} - \frac{4}{7}t, t\right) \mid t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

Could you please explain how this parametrization is achieved?

When I solve for a variable in $L_1$ and insert into $L_2$ and $L_3$ I end up with two identical equations, which means there are infinitely many solutions. I'm stuck on how I get from that to the answer above.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L_2+L_3:6x+6y+6z=0$$
$$2x+2y+2z=0=L_1=L_2+L_3$$

You see the system of 3 equations is really just 2 equations, first of the three is redundant.

So, we solve only two equations for 3 variables, so get the parameterisation.

To visualize it, $L_3,L_2$ represent planes in $3-D$ so, their intersection is a line which has infinite points.

Comment: Your answers was very clear and simple. Thanks. But how come the answer only has 1 parameter when there are three variables?

Comment: @JohnSmith  My pleasure, you can accept answers. Read [about page](http://math.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: It means you can take $z$ to be any real value which we denote by $t$ and then deduce $x$ and $y$. you could choose to fix $x=t$ and deduce $y$ and $z$ or fix $y=t$ and deduce $x$ and $z$.

Comment: @palio Yes of course !

Comment: @exploringnet My dear exploringnet i did not downvote you!!

Comment: @palio Great explanation. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many solutions; the system of linear equations is linearly dependent. That is, the parameter $t$ was chosen to represent $z$, and the other variables are functions of the variable $z = t$.

If you use row reduction on the augmented coefficient matrix corresponding to the system of equations, you'd find that your third row is all zeros.

Any vector of the form $\begin{pmatrix} -1/7 \\ 1/7 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + t\begin{pmatrix} -1/3 \\ -4/7 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac 17 - \frac 13t \\ \frac 17 - \frac 47 t \\ t \end{pmatrix}$ will solve the system of equations.

That is, every $t \in \mathbb R$ determines a unique solution. Since there are infinitely many $t \in \mathbb R$, one will have infinitely many vectors solving the system, one vector per $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Once we assign $z = t,$ $t\in \mathbb R$, $x$ is determined, as is $y$.